# What's the difference of lifetime inference between async fn and async closure?

Tags: rust, async-await, closures, lifetime

Look at this code:

```
#![feature(async_closure)]

use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

trait A<'a> {
    fn call(&'a self, data: &'a i32) -> Pin<Box<dyn 'a + Future<Output=()>>>;
}

impl <'a, F, Fut> A<'a> for F
where Fut: 'a + Future<Output=()>,
      F: Fn(&'a i32) -> Fut
{
    fn call(&'a self, data: &'a i32) -> Pin<Box<dyn 'a + Future<Output=()>>> {
        Box::pin(self(data))
    }
}

async fn sample(_data: &i32) {

}

fn is_a(_: impl for<'a> A<'a>) {

}

fn main() {
    is_a(sample);
    is_a(async move |data: &i32| {
        println!("data: {}", data);
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=01b701d44c56024de03004a983cb083e)

Why does `is_a(sample)` works but the next line fails to be compiled? What's the difference of lifetime inference between async fn and async closure?

The closure version fails with the following error:

```
error: implementation of `A` is not general enough
  --> src/main.rs:29:5
   |
6  | / trait A<'a> {
7  | |     fn call(&'a self, data: &'a i32) -> Pin<Box<dyn 'a + Future<Output=()>>>;
8  | | }
   | |_- trait `A` defined here
...
29 |       is_a(async move |data: &i32| {
   |       ^^^^ implementation of `A` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `A<'1>` would have to be implemented for the type `[closure@src/main.rs:29:10: 31:6]`, for any lifetime `'1`...
   = note: ...but `A<'_>` is actually implemented for the type `[closure@src/main.rs:29:10: 31:6]`, for some specific lifetime `'2`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of an `async ||` closure is an anonymous type generated by the compiler.

Such type implements a `Future` and it captures an additional
lifetime related to the scope of the `async ||` closure.

```
fn main() {

    let closure = async move |data: &i32| {   --+ '2 start
        println!("data: {}", data);             |
    };                                          |
                                                |
    is_a(closure);                              |
                                                v 
}
```

The async block returns a type with signature like:

```
impl Future<Output = SomeType> + '2 + '...
```

Where `'2` is the lifetime of the closure.

Note that there isn't this additional lifetime requirement when using an async function instead of a closure.

When you call `is_a` like this:

```
let closure = async move |data: &i32| {
    println!("data: {}", data);
};

is_a(closure);
```

You get:

```
error: implementation of `A` is not general enough
...
= note: `A<'1>` would have to be implemented for the type `[closure@src/main.rs:43:19: 45:6]`, for any lifetime `'1`...
= note: ...but `A<'_>` is actually implemented for the type `[closure@src/main.rs:43:19: 45:6]`, for some specific lifetime `'2`
```

because the `closure` argument is a type implemented for a specific lifetime `'2` but any lifetime is required:

```
fn is_a(_: impl for<'a> A<'a>) {}
```

Note that the error you notice indeed hides another lifetime violation that originate from the captured `'2` lifetime.

For:

```
let closure = async move |data: &i32| {
    println!("data: {}", data);
};
```

the compiler reports:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:43:19
   |
43 |     let closure = async move |data: &i32| {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-^^^-
   |                   |                 |   |
   |                   |                 |   return type of closure is impl std::future::Future
   |                   |                 let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
   |                   returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

that let me conclude that it is not possible to use argument references inside an `async ||` closure.

### Why is it needed lifetime '2?

The lifetime concept is about memory safety and it boils down to garantee that a reference
pointing to a memory slot is pointing to a valid value.

```
fn my_function() {

    let value = 1                           --+ '1 start           
                                              |
    let closure = async move |data: &i32| {   |       --+ '2 start
        println!("data: {}", data);           |         |
    };                                        |         |
                                              |         |
    tokio::spawn(closure(&value))             |         |
                                             -+ '1 end  |
}                                                       v continue until   
                                                          the future complete
```

Consider the above example: value is a memory slot allocated on the stack and it will be valid until
`my_function` returns and the stack unwind.

The lifetime `'1` take account of the scope of validity of `value`, when `my_function` returns
the reference `&value` is not more valid.

But from where is coming lifetime `'2`?

It is because `closure(&value)` returns an entity that implements a `Future` that will live into the runtime executor,
in this case the tokio executor, until the computation will end.

The `'2` lifetime will take this scope of validity of the `Future` into account.

For making a reason of `'2` lifetime necessity consider the following scenario:

```
fn run_asyn_closure() {
    let data: i32 = 1;

    let closure = async move |data: &i32| {
        println!("starting task with data {}", data);

        // yield the computation for 3 seconds, awaiting for completion of long_running_task
        long_running_task().await;

        // data points to a memory slot on the stack that meantime is rewritten
        // because run_asyn_closure returned 3 seconds ago
        println!("using again data: {}", data); // BANG!! data is not more valid
    };

    tokio::spawn(closure(&data));
}
```

Note that in reality `tokio::spawn` needs that `&data` reference has `'static` lifetime,
but this is irrelevant to understand this theme.

Comment: An async version of [rfc1558](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1558-closure-to-fn-coercion.md) is necessary.

Comment: I grasp what you mean, but for what I understand this could be forbidden by the memory safety rules of rust.
Behind an async function/block there is a state machine needed to track the progress toward a completion that will occurs at some future point in time.

Try to visualize a (forbidden by rust) scenario where the `data: &i32` reference is initially stored into the state machine, after that the value it points it is dropped (`data` become invalid) and at some time farther in the future the state machine make some progress and try to use an invalid `data` reference ...

Comment: It's reasonable that the lifetime of `GenFuture` relies on lifetime of `data`. But why does it have to rely on lifetime of closure?

Comment: Because the closure (or perhaps it is better say `closure()` in this case) evaluate to a Future which lifetime may outlive `data` and this is noticed by the compiler.

Comment: It's confusing... For what I understand, the `GenFuture` doesn't capture any reference from the `closure()`, it only contains a parameter reference `data`. In this case, the lifetime of future shouldn't rely on the `closure()`, should it? Does the future contain any reference of the `closure()`?

Comment: I've updated the answer, I hope now it is more clear.

Comment: Thx for your answer, there are still two doubts.
The first one, as the closure does not capture any variable from environments, why does it not be cast to a normal anonymous function as [rfc1558](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1558-closure-to-fn-coercion.md)?
The last one, as your explanation, why does [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5b2766e596d666efa1163af5c5b653c) work?

Comment: How to extend rfc1558 for `async ||` closures, coercing an `async ||` closure to a `fn` pointer?

A `|| {} ` closure boils down to a function entity, but `async || {}`
boils down to a function + state entity.

I suppose your code compile because data reference get unused, there is not need to keep track of data validity with a lifetime.
Try to use `data` inside the body of `async ||` block to see again lifetime issues.