# How to store and use an optional closure that accepts a reference and returns a future?

Tags: struct, rust, async-await, closures

I have an async function `save` that has a `Save` struct as argument which optionally contains an async function (`validator`). The problem is that the following code only works when `Some(..)` is specified, with `None` the compiler throws an error.

```rust
use std::future::Future;

trait SomeTrait {}

enum SomeError {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct User {}

impl SomeTrait for User {}

struct Save<T, F>
where
    T: SomeTrait,
    F: Future<Output = Result<(), SomeError>>,
{
    pub validator: Option<Box<dyn Fn(&T) -> F>>,
}

async fn save<T, F>(obj: &T, args: Save<T, F>) -> Result<(), SomeError>
where
    T: SomeTrait,
    F: Future<Output = Result<(), SomeError>>,
{
    if let Some(v) = args.validator {
        (*v)(obj).await?;
    }
    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::test]
async fn test_func() {
    let user = User {};

    save(&user, Save { validator: None }).await;
    save(
        &user,
        Save {
            validator: Some(Box::new(|obj| async {
                println!("input: {:?}", obj);
                Ok(())
            })),
        },
    )
    .await;
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0698]: type inside `async` block must be known in this context
  --> test_utils/src/testin.rs:35:17
   |
35 |     save(&user, Save { validator: None }).await;
   |                 ^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `F` declared on the struct `Save`
   |
note: the type is part of the `async` block because of this `await`
  --> test_utils/src/testin.rs:35:5
   |
35 |     save(&user, Save { validator: None }).await;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I make the above code work? Is there an alternative implementation without the use of the `F` generic parameter in the `Save` struct? I can work with it for now, but might become unwieldy when there are multiple functions in the `Save` struct.

Comment: "async closures are unstable" — if you are using unstable features, you **must** note which nightly version you are using. If you aren't using a nightly compiler, you aren't using async closures. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: See also [What is the difference between `|_| async move {}` and `async move |_| {}`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59156473/155423); [What's the difference of lifetime inference between async fn and async closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60751127/155423)

Comment: See also  [How to accept an async function as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60717746/155423); [How to indicate that the lifetime of an async function's return value is the same as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60621816/155423).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I'm reading the pages you referred now, and will update my question soon

Comment: I think my case is different because of the use of an Option, the problem arises only when using `None`.

Comment: Looks like the code you posted [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66c65b1faf1973ba30d0727603ea60bd) does solve my problem, calling `.boxed()` on the async block was the missing link for me. I would accept that code as an answer, and I think it is valuable for others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using `BoxFuture`

Since you want to hide the type, using a trait object is useful. `BoxFuture` is well-suited for this, combined with the `boxed` method to create it:

```
use futures::{future::BoxFuture, FutureExt};
```

```
struct Save<T>
where
    T: SomeTrait,
{
    pub validator: Option<Box<dyn Fn(&T) -> BoxFuture<Result<(), SomeError>>>>,
}
```

```
let _ = save(
    &user,
    Save {
        validator: Some(Box::new(|obj| {
            async move {
                println!("input: {:?}", obj);
                Ok(())
            }
            .boxed()
        })),
    },
)
.await;
```

See also:

- [How can one await a result of a boxed future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60561573/155423)
- [Cannot use `impl Future` to store async function in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58354633/155423)
- [How do I erase the type of future in the new future API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54452339/155423)

## Using None with a generic type

The problem here is that the generic type must be known, even if you aren't using it because you've picked `None`. You could provide a type that fits the constraints (implements `Future`, `Output` is a `Result<(), SomeError>`). Here I use [`Ready`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/struct.Ready.html):

```
type Dummy = futures::future::Ready<Result<(), SomeError>>;

save::<_, Dummy>(&user, Save { validator: None }).await;
```

Unfortunately, this creates an error I don't know how to solve yet ("borrowed data cannot be stored outside of its closure").

See also:

- [Create a generic struct with Option<T> without specifying T when instantiating with None](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42141129/155423)
- [Pass None into a function that accepts Option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37886379/155423)
- [Is there a way to hint to the compiler to use some kind of default generic type when using Option::None?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58593042/155423)